# SSHParamiko is giving unknown error when calling the "main connection" in two different functions

Tags: python, paramiko

This is the ssh paramiko connection class:
File name: ssh_module.py

```
class ssh_connection:
    def __init__(self,username,password,port,host):
        self.host=host
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.port = port
        self.trans='False'
        self.sftp_is='False'    

    def connect(self):
        self.trans='True'
        self.transport=paramiko.Transport((self.host,self.port))
        self.transport.connect(username=self.username, password=self.password)  
        stdout.write("\r%s" % "Connected")
        print ("\n")
        stdout.flush()

    def sftp_connect(self): 
        self.sftp_is='True'
        #self.transport=self.get_transport()
        self.sftp=paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(self.transport)


    def close(self):
        if self.trans=='True':
            print 'here'
            self.transport.close()
            self.trans='False'
        if self.sftp_is=='True':
            print 'self trans'
            self.sftp.close()
            self.sftp_is='False'


    def execute(self,command):
        to_exec = self.transport.open_session()
        to_exec.setblocking(0)
        to_exec.exec_command(command)
        if to_exec.recv_exit_status():
            print 'Command did not executed'
            to_exec.close()
        print (command, " Executed")
        print ("\n")
        to_exec.close()
```

Another file add_host.py

```
class server():

    def host(self):
       ip='192.168.1.101'
       passwd='xyz'
       connection = ssh_module.ssh_connection('root',passwd,22,ip)
       connection.connect()
       print 'Connected'
       connection.close()
       self.set_directory(ip,passwd)

    def set_directory(self,ip,passwd):
      connection1 = ssh_module.ssh_connection('root',passwd,22,ip)
      connection1.execute('x.txt')
      connection1.close()
main=server()
main.host()
```

When I ran it gives following error. Any help is appreciated. I tried couple of things but nothing worked out. Whenever the program hit the execute portion, it throws error.

```
File "/home/hhhh/Desktop/GUI/test/pycode/ssh_module.py", line 40, in execute
to_exec = self.transport.open_session()
AttributeError: ssh_connection instance has no attribute 'transport'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you are calling `connect` method before calling `sftp_connect`.

Always call connect first

try this

```
import ssh_module

class server():

    def host(self):
       ip='127.0.0.1'
       passwd='xyz'
       connection = ssh_module.ssh_connection('abc',passwd,22,ip)
       print "Connec:"
       connection.connect()
       print 'Connected'
       connection.close()
       self.set_directory(ip,passwd)

    def set_directory(self,ip,passwd):
      connection1 = ssh_module.ssh_connection('abc',passwd,22,ip)
      connection1.connect() # Connect before use.
      connection1.execute('x.txt')
      connection1.close()
main=server()
main.host()
```

Comment: The connect function works file, its the issue with the execute function, which whenever called for the second time in an another function, gives that error.

Comment: will you please provide the code which create the error. I try to run same at my local machine to check the error.

Comment: Code edited. If you just paste the code in the two files as mentioned above, you will get the error message. Let me know if you need anything else. I appreciate your help man.